# Javascript Checking Keyboard Input

Tags: javascript, events

Any tips on how to write a JS function to check user input before posting to HTML page?

Using this so far:

```
document.onkeyup = function(event){
    if (event.key >= 65 && event.key <=90){
    guessesList.push(userChoice);
    }
};
```

but doesn't seem to do anything when I refresh the page. The input needs to be only a letter, not a number or other input key.

Comment: you can use `match()` to make sure only letters are passed by using a regex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) { run code within here
 }  else {
  guessesList.pop(userChoice);
 
 }
^^for future users, this is what I ended up using, with my page entered within the if function. Thanks everybody who commented with helpful info!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare each character with `keyCode`. Thus you need to change:

`event.key` to `event.keyCode`

You can do something like the following:

```js
function myFunction(event){
  console.log(event.keyCode)
  if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <=90){
    //guessesList.push(userChoice);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Sample text" id="test" onkeyup="myFunction(event)" />
```

Comment: Please note `event.keyCode` is depreciated ([KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)). It's better to use `event.key` instead ([KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyCode` property.

```js
function myFunction(event){
  if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <=90){
     console.log(event.key);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Sample text" id="test" onkeyup="myFunction(event)" />
```

Comment: Please note `event.keyCode` is depreciated ([KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)). It's better to use `event.key` instead ([KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `pattern` attribute with regexp (it should be `[A-Za-z]+` in your case) to your `input` element, and then check validity using `inputElement.checkValidity()` method, which returns `true` or `false`, which means is your input valid or invalid:

```js
function validate(inputEl) {
  console.log(inputEl.checkValidity());
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" onkeyup="validate(this)" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" />
```